# Opacity based on scroll position, cap at specific opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this piece of code to animate the background of my header, based on the scroll position of the window:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var st=$(window).scrollTop();
    $('#whitebackground').animate({opacity: st / 200 },1);
});
```

Meaning that when scrolling more than 200px from the top, the opacity of the background div will be 1.

However, what if I want to cap this opacity range, so that it doesn't exceed 0.9 for instance?

Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Math.min()` to select the lowest value from a list:

```
$('#whitebackground').animate({ opacity: Math.min(st / 200, 0.9) }, 1);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pfqeaax1/)

Note that the max value in the fiddle is `0.5` to make the effect more obvious.